how to record java execute path?
I want to know my customer how to use my application. for example, i have a spring-web applicaiton. customer call the service 100 times.
i want to analyst every time service's execute path.
eg.
1 time execute path : code line 1,2,5,7
80 time execute path : code line 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
19 time execute path : code line 8,9,8,7
by this way, i can make some analyst , like the situation 1 is money not enough, situation 2 is order success. situation 3 is use by credit card and so on.  it helps me know the market situation better. is it anyone can give me some advice ,thinks

I don't think there is a way recoding the code lines. And I don't think it's a good way even if there is a way.
You should check the Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring. You can log every invocation along with arguments and the result.
